# Error 404 when i'm up my page using vercel

Tags: javascript, html, vercel

it's my first time here.

I'm trying to up my application into vercel, but i'm facing the 404 error.

My project have 3 pages.

the main page: `pagina-inicial > index.html`
the 2nd: `inserindo-informacoes > index.html`
3rd one: `exibindo-times > index.html`

In the first page i have a `<a>` that redirect to the `inserindo-informacoes/index.html`. And in the index of `inserindo-informacoes` also have a `<a>` that redirect to `exibindo-times`

I'm using that code in "vercel.json":

([print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0rcN.png))

whats wrong there?

thanks!

I tried to change but in can't fix.

I expect to solve the problem.